# In Node, how to check that a particular object is an instance of ChildProcess

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I'm trying to check (in an unit test) if a particular object is an ChildProcess, but I can't seem to get a reference to that class (which is here https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/lib/child_process.js )

what I would like do do is something like

```
selenium = require('selenium-standalone')
spawnOptions = { stdio: 'pipe' }
seleniumArgs = ['-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./node_modules/nodewebkit/nodewebkit/chromedriver']
@server = selenium(spawnOptions, seleniumArgs)

expect(server).to.be.an.instanceof(ChildProcess)
```

but I don't seem to figure out where to get the reference to ChildProcess

UPDATE: based on the answer provided, I'm now testing using:

```
it 'start()', (done)->
  selenium.start.assert_Is_Function()
  selenium.start ->
    selenium.server.assert_Is_Not_Null()
    selenium.server.constructor.assert_Is_Function()
    selenium.server.constructor.name.assert_Is('ChildProcess')
    done()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`child_process` module](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) doesn't export its `ChildProcess` class. You can easily access `server`'s constructor, but you don't have anything to compare it with.

I can see two options for you.

### Check that `server`'s constructor name is `ChildProcess`

```
expect(server).to.have.property('constuctor');
expect(server.constuctor).to.have.property('name', 'ChildProcess');
```

You may also add a check that `server.constuctor` is inherited from `EventEmitter`

```
expect(server).to.be.an.instanceof(require('events').EventEmitter);
```

### Acquire `ChildProcess` class from `spawn` call

But it you want to be sure that `server` is a `ChildProcess` and not a mock, then you could acquire `ChildProcess` class from [`spawn` call](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
ChildProcess = require('child_process').spawn('echo').constructor; // use any command
```

the you'll be able to use it to verify your `server` object:

```
expect(server).to.be.an.instanceof(ChildProcess);
```

If you don't want to actually spawn anything, you could use any non-existing command. Just don't forget to specify an error handler to prevent `child_process` from throwing an error:

```
child = require('child_process').spawn('non-existing-command');
child.on('error', function() {}); // empty error handler
ChildProcess = child.constructor;
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I updated the question to show how I ended up testing it

Comment: Hey Dinis -- just curious as I'm interested in "why" - why are you needing to check if object is instanceOf childProcess? - Just in case I run across a need later on in my coding. Thanks!

Comment: @jamesemanon I'm two years late and I can't speak for Dinis, but the reason I am checking is in a unit test, to be sure that the function I'm testing returns a child process like it should.

Answer (score 1):

`child_process` exposes the `ChildProcess` class as of node 4.0.

```
var ChildProcess = require('child_process').ChildProcess
expect(server).to.be.an.instanceof(ChildProcess)
```

Added in PR: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/1760